# Regex in Google sheets: Extract domains with several subdirectories from a list with urls

Tags: regex, url, google-sheets-formula

I need to extract domains with given subdirectories - /news/, /editorials/, /politics/, /opinion/, /second-opinions/, /editorials/ etc - from a list of urls, for example:

`https://www.medpagetoday.com/opinion/second-opinions/104083 > medpagetoday.com/opinion https://www.politico.com/news/2023/04/18/bidens-tax-returns-00092675 > politico.com/news`

When several sections are present, extract to the highest in the hierarchy. For example, in case of  /opinion/ and /editorials/:
`https://www.nytimes.com/2023/04/14/opinion/editorials/clarence-thomas-trips-supreme-court.html > nytimes.com/2023/04/14/opinion`

I've found regexreplace that works on removing http(s) and www:

```
=ArrayFormula(REGEXREPLACE(A1:A,".*(^|www\.|//)(.+)\b/?$","$2"))
```

but not sure how to expand it further.

Edited:
I ended up with the following solution, which looks crude but seems to be working:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(""&A2:A,"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www[0-9]*\.)?(.*?\/(news|opinions?|editorials?))(?:\/.*)?$"),""))`

Still struggling how to truncate complex subdomains of any length to domains, like in hypothetical
`https://m.sports.yahoo.co.jp/news/202301110/ > yahoo.co.jp/news`.
It can be any TLD/ccTLD.

Comment: Can you provide info on how `/opinion/, /second-opinions/` both are extracted in first use-case of medpagetoday but its kinda restricted to `/opinion/` *` /editorials/` skipped* for nytimes?!

Comment: Your examples and stated goals are not consistent. Please (a) restate your desired behavior (*"When several sections are present, extract to the highest level in the hierarchy."*) or (b) update the examples. The Medpage example goes **2** levels deep (`/opinion/second-opinions/`). The Politico example goes **1** level deep (`/news/`). The NYTimes example goes **4** levels deep (`/2023/04/14/opinion/`).

Comment: Please show several examples of input and the parts(s) of it you want to match. Is it that you want to extract the first part of the URL that is after the server name and that is composed of letters?

Comment: Thank you for your questions, I updated the description to make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to pull the highest in the hierarchy, use:

```
=BYROW(A1:A,LAMBDA(r,IF(r="","",REGEXEXTRACT(r,"^.*(?:www\.)(.+\.com/\w+)"))))
```

[image: Screenshot of examples]
Note: this accomplishes the stated goal, but 2 of 3 of the example URLs are not real pages, but this may not matter for your specific use case.

Answer (score 0):

Can you test:

```
=index(if(regexmatch(A2:A,"\.co\."),regexextract(A2:A,"(?:/|\.|^)([^\./]*\.co\..*"&textjoin("|",1,C:C)&")"),
       ifna(regexextract(A2:A,"(?:(?:ftp|https?://)?w*\.*)?(.*?(?:"&textjoin("|",1,C:C)&"))"))))
```

- the directories list is arranged in `Column_C` of my test sheet

[image]